# Spring AOP is not working in with MVC structure

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I am using the following structure but failing but failing to create the proxy call.

In controller-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />    
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

In application-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.common" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dao" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />   

    <!-- Aspect Bean Definition 
    <bean id="aspectBean" class="com.common.AspectImple" /> -->
```

Aspect class

```
package com.common;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectImple {


    @Before("execution(* com.controller.JobController.*(..))")
        public void beforeImpl() {
           System.out.println("  Before Done ");
    }

}
```

Controller class

```
@Controller
    public class JobController {

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/xyz")
        public ModelAndView abc(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
            ...
            m1(10);
            ...
            }
    }

    public void m1(int i){
        System.out.println(" AOP Done ");
    }
```

The AOP is not working and during call of abc(..) & m1(..) method, beforeImpl() is not getting called. Could someone please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: yes. My maven dependencies for AOP..                              <dependency>   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.12</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.12</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>cglib</groupId>
   <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Sorry I am unable to edit it properly. Aspectjrt, Aspectjweaver and cglib has been used

Comment: It doesn't work on neither abc() and m1()?

Comment: Yes, none of them are working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about move

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dao" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

from application-context.xml to controller-servlet.xml?

The aspects and the beans to be applied needs to be in the same ApplicationContext but ApplicationContext is not aware of WebApplicationContext .

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue but am using Annotation based configuration. To get AOP working for @Controller, this did the trick:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mypackage"})
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{
    ...

    @Bean
    public MyAspect myAspect()
    {
        return new MyAspect();
    }

}
```

Comment: provide an xml based solution as well as that was the intended question

Comment: This. TL;DR check aspect file extension - should be .java, not .aj. I was having a very particular error where maven wouldn't compile the aspect and I was receiving the "symbol not found" error. Turns out that indeed maven was not creating the .class file for my aspect (check your .m2 repository), but that's because 1st time I created an .aj aspect source file and not a .java one. In between I changed to java class in the source code, but forgot to also update the file extension. This answer helped me debugg.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP Advice on Annotated Controllers - is a good answer
http://mergetag.com/spring-aop-advice-on-annotated-controllers-2/